# How to install Cairo on R (Termux) with freetype support

Tags: r, linux, termux

I failed to install Cairo package on R(Termux) with:

```
install.packages('Cairo')
```

because of it doesn't find freetype support:

```
configure: error: Cannot use cairo-ft backend, 
although cairo claims it is working. Please check 
your caito installation and/or update cairo if 
necessary or set CAIRO_CFLAGS/CAIRO_LIBS 
accordingly.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Cairo’
* removing  
 ‘/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/R/library/Cairo’
sh: ȫ�: not found
```

I read here [Install Cairo on R](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/r-help-archive/HBeGTTMTU5c/ZJlU2QylH3MJ) that the OP 'had to recompile cairo with --enable-ft=yes. 
'. I would need to know if this solves the installation failure on R and how to do it on Termux.

Comment: I have the same issue on macOS Catalina - cannot install Cairo. Any advice? 

I tried the above solution, restarted RStudio, Terminal but same got the same error

> Cannot use cairo-ft backend, although cairo claims it is working. Please
> check your caito installation and/or update cairo if necessary or set
> CAIRO_CFLAGS/CAIRO_LIBS accordingly. ERROR: configuration failed for
> package ‘Cairo’
> * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Cairo’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘Cairo’ had non-zero exit
> status

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/lib
export CAIRO_INCLUDE_PATH=$PREFIX/include/cairo
export CAIRO_CFLAGS=-I$PREFIX/include/cairo
export CAIRO_LIBS='-L$PREFIX/lib -lcairo'
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to build cairo for a different purpose, but also had the problem of freetype library not being found.

First, cairo's `configure` is printing `checking for FREETYPE...` but it is not actually looking for `FREETYPE` or `freetype`, it is looking for `freetype2`.

Second, freetype library has 2 versioning systems (one returning 2.X and other one returning 9.Y).

Inside `configure`, around line 30659 there is a such fragment:

```sh
# We use pkg-config to look for freetype2, but fall back to
# freetype-config if it fails.  We prefer pkg-config, since we can
# then just put freetype2 >= $FREETYPE_MIN_VERSION in
# Requires.private, but at least up to 2003-06-07, there was no
# freetype2.pc in the release.
#
# FreeType versions come in three forms:
#   release (such as 2.1.9)
#   libtool (such as 9.7.3) (returned by freetype-config and pkg-config)
#   platform-specific/soname (such as 6.3.4)
# and they recommend you never use the platform-specific version
# (see docs/VERSION.DLL in freetype2 sources)
#
# Set these as appropriate:

# release number - for information only
FREETYPE_MIN_RELEASE=2.1.9
# libtool-specific version - this is what is checked
FREETYPE_MIN_VERSION=9.7.3
```

In my case, pkg-config was using the 2.X one. Chaning the value of `FREETYPE_MIN_VERSION` to the value of `FREETYPE_MIN_RELEASE` fixed the problem.